# Error: @default only accepts scalar types, which might be why the array lints badly

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I'm trying to `amplify push` my updated `amplify/backend/api/<myAPIName>/schema.graphql` file. I am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred during the push operation: /
Schema validation failed.

Expected type String, found ["Admins", "Users"].

canRead: [String] @default(value: ["Admins", "Users"])

Expected type String, found ["Admins", "Users"].
```

The offending code in `schema.graphql`:

```
type Card {
  ...
  canRead: [String] @default(value: ["Admins", "Users"])
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set a field "canRead" on my Card object. The field should be an array of strings. I want the default value to be `["Admins", "Users"]`, but Amplify/graphql only accepts Scalar types for default values.

The [GraphQL documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types) lists things such as integers and strings as Scalar types, but then confusingly says that "appearsIn" will resolve to a scalar in the provided example:

> ```
> {
>    "data": {
>     "hero": {
>       "name": "R2-D2",
>       "appearsIn": [
>         "NEWHOPE",
>         "EMPIRE",
>         "JEDI"
>       ]
>     }
> }
> ```

Which I took to mean that an array of strings might also be considered a scalar, but apparently not or else my code would presumably work?

The documentation goes on to tease with the following:

> In most GraphQL service implementations, there is also a way to
> specify custom scalar types. For example, we could define a Date type:
>
> `scalar Date`
>
> Then it's up to our implementation to define how
> that type should be serialized, deserialized, and validated. For
> example, you could specify that the Date type should always be
> serialized into an integer timestamp, and your client should know to
> expect that format for any date fields.

But it doesn't describe how to do this, and what the limitations are. Can anyone advise if/how defining a default array of strings can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Had something similar come up recently also.

I don't think you can specify a default for an Array, only scalar types as mentioned in the docs here: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#assign-default-values-for-fields I think the tease *"and more"* refers to the AWS specific types referenced here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html which covers off `ID`, `Int`, `String`, `Float`, `Boolean` and some exotic types from AWS like `AWSDateTime`

My option was to set on creation - Not the answer you're looking for but hope it helps.